# MS Graph API: Returns old value of range updated using non-persistent session

Tags: postman, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I've been playing around with Microsoft Graph API using Postman. I created an excel sheet in my OneDrive and I am trying to update a row using the Update Range endpoint. However, I don't want the updated results to persist. I just want to retrieve the updated row after the PATCH request. There are calculated columns whos value is what I am interested in. So I am using a non-persistent workbook session. Here are the steps:

1. Get a non-persistent workbook session
2. Update a range (PATCH) in an excel workbook passing the non-persistent session in the request header
3. Get the value of range using the same non-persistent session

This works perfectly using CURL requests or in a Node app. But when I try the same using Postman, step# 3 returns old value of the range.

Has anyone run into a similar issue with postman? Here is the postman collection I am using for the above scenario - https://pastebin.pl/view/f4ea66dd

```
    {
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "0b8d1a0c-0d34-4c34-8561-d89a74bec345",
        "name": "MS Graph Update Range Chaning Example",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Get App-Only Access Token",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "id": "6c7fbffd-3a06-4dd1-b972-0ab11c2a9f16",
                        "exec": [
                            "try {\r",
                            "    if (pm.environment.get(\"ClientID\") === \"\")\r",
                            "    {\r",
                            "        console.log(\"You need to enter *ClientID* environment variable first.\");\r",
                            "    }\r",
                            "    if (pm.environment.get(\"ClientSecret\") === \"\")\r",
                            "    {\r",
                            "        console.log(\"You need to enter *ClientSecret* environment variable first.\");\r",
                            "    }\r",
                            "    if (pm.environment.get(\"TenantID\") === \"\")\r",
                            "    {\r",
                            "        console.log(\"You need to enter *TenantID* environment variable first.\");\r",
                            "    }\r",
                            "    else\r",
                            "    {\r",
                            "        var json = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "        postman.setEnvironmentVariable(\"AppAccessToken\", json.access_token);\r",
                            "        console.log(postman.AppAccessToken);\r",
                            "    }\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "catch (e) {\r",
                            "    console.log(e);\r",
                            "}\r",
                            "\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "SdkVersion",
                        "value": "postman-graph/v1.0",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "urlencoded",
                    "urlencoded": [
                        {
                            "key": "grant_type",
                            "value": "client_credentials",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "client_id",
                            "value": "{{ClientID}}",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "client_secret",
                            "value": "{{ClientSecret}}",
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        {
                            "key": "scope",
                            "value": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
                            "type": "text"
                        }
                    ],
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "text"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "login",
                        "microsoftonline",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "{{TenantID}}",
                        "oauth2",
                        "v2.0",
                        "token"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Create Non-Persistent Session",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "id": "7682ccd5-c33e-40dc-b503-e963c231a3ba",
                        "exec": [
                            "var json = JSON.parse(responseBody);",
                            "postman.setEnvironmentVariable('workbookSessionId', json.id);"
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "bearer",
                    "bearer": [
                        {
                            "key": "token",
                            "value": "{{AppAccessToken}}",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{\n    \"persistChanges\": false\n}",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/{{exceldocid}}/workbook/createSession",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "graph",
                        "microsoft",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "v1.0",
                        "drive",
                        "items",
                        "{{exceldocid}}",
                        "workbook",
                        "createSession"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Update Range",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "id": "7682ccd5-c33e-40dc-b503-e963c231a3ba",
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "bearer",
                    "bearer": [
                        {
                            "key": "token",
                            "value": "{{AppAccessToken}}",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "PATCH",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Workbook-Session-Id",
                        "value": "{{workbookSessionId}}",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{\n    \"values\": [ \n        [\"Toledo\", \"toledo@blacklist.com\", \"456-223-7633\"]\n    ]\n}",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/{{exceldocid}}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(address='A3:C3')",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "graph",
                        "microsoft",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "v1.0",
                        "drive",
                        "items",
                        "{{exceldocid}}",
                        "workbook",
                        "worksheets('Sheet1')",
                        "range(address='A3:C3')"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get Range",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "id": "7682ccd5-c33e-40dc-b503-e963c231a3ba",
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                "disableBodyPruning": true
            },
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "bearer",
                    "bearer": [
                        {
                            "key": "token",
                            "value": "{{AppAccessToken}}",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Workbook-Session_Id",
                        "value": "{{workbookSessionId}}",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/items/{{exceldocid}}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(address='A3:C3')",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "graph",
                        "microsoft",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "v1.0",
                        "drive",
                        "items",
                        "{{exceldocid}}",
                        "workbook",
                        "worksheets('Sheet1')",
                        "range(address='A3:C3')"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "id": "f1768e09-9e37-4152-bf40-6e3a122f88a4",
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "id": "316e2e84-abdb-42be-9ba5-f29d2c312128",
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}
```

Comment: I know i am late. But i failed to access the postman collection, as i wanted to give a try...

Comment: @Dev Updated the question to include the collection

Comment: Thanks @sfdev_CA, i will look into this. Being said that, CURL works. It means no issue with Microsoft Graph API. Rather it sounds like the way that you implemented in POSTMAN or the AAD workflow, cross check the same against custom app and it  should be the same. In addition, I would validate the tokens/scopes/permissions etc too - something may be different.